# Spark group by several fields several times on the same RDD

Tags: optimization, apache-spark, group-by, aggregate, pyspark

My data is stored in `csv` format, and the headers are given in the `column_names` variable.

I wrote the following code to read it into a python dictionary RDD

```
rdd=sc.textFile(hdfs_csv_dir)\
.map(lambda x: x.split(','))\
.filter(lambda row: len(row)==len(column_names))\
.map(lambda row: dict([(column,row[index]) for index,column in enumerate(column_names)]))
```

Next, I wrote a function that counts the combinations of column values given the column names

```
import operator
def count_by(rdd,cols=[]):
    '''
    Equivalent to:
     SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) FROM MX3 GROUP BY col1, col2;
    But the number of columns can be more than 2
    '''
    counts=rdd.map(lambda x: (','.join([str(x[c]) for c in cols]), 1))\
    .reduceByKey(operator.add)\
    .map(lambda t:t[0].split(',')+[t[1]])\
    .collect()
    return counts
```

I am running `count_by` several times, with a lot of different parameters on the same `rdd`.

What is the best way to optimize the query and make it run faster ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should **cache** the RDD (by calling `cachedRdd = rdd.cache()`) before passing it multiple times into `count_by`, to prevent Spark from loading it from disk for each operation. Operating on a cached RDD means data will be loaded to memory upon first use (first call to `count_by`), then read from memory for following calls.

You should also consider using Spark [DataFrame API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframes) instead of the lower-level RDD API, since:

- You seem to articulate your intentions using SQL, and DataFrame API allows you to actually use such a dialect
- When using DataFrames, Spark can perform some extra optimizations since it has a better understanding of *what* you are trying to do, is it can design the best way to achieve it. SQL-like dialect is declerative - you only say what you want, not how to get it, which gives Spark more freedom to optimize

Comment: If I were to query several `select c1,c2,count(*) from (....)` from the same source (denoted `(....)`), will SparkSQL know to cache it on it's own ?

Comment: I think you'll have to cache it anyway, or call `dataframe.registerTempTable("table-name")` which would achieve the same effect, I think